# How to set width of TreeViewer in PreferenceDialog

Tags: eclipse, swt

For some reasons I disabled zooming for my app: `System.setProperty("swt.autoScale", "false");`

```
public class Application implements IApplication
{
  private static final String ProcessName = "myName.exe";

  /* (non-Javadoc)
   * @see org.eclipse.equinox.app.IApplication#start(org.eclipse.equinox.app.IApplicationContext)
   */
  public Object start(IApplicationContext context) throws Exception
  {
    OpenDocumentEventProcessor openDocProcessor = new OpenDocumentEventProcessor();
          
    // Eclipse4 has a bug while scaling images for high DPI monitors
    System.setProperty("swt.autoScale", "false");
    
    Display display = PlatformUI.createDisplay();
    display.addListener(SWT.OpenDocument, openDocProcessor);
    display.addListener(SWT.OpenUrl, openDocProcessor);

    //other code
  }
}
```

After that, while creating preference pages, contents area is too narrow and horizontal scrollbar appears there, see picture. Has anyone idea, where to enlarge this Composite?

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXMFl.png)

creating preference dialog:

```
public class SettingsToolItem
{
  // some code

  @Execute
  public void execute()
  {
    try
    {
      String openPreferencesID = lastSelectedPageID;

      // some code

      Shell shell = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getShell();

      PreferenceDialog prefDialog = PreferencesUtil.createPreferenceDialogOn(shell, openPreferencesID, null, null);

      prefDialog.getTreeViewer().expandToLevel(2);

      prefDialog.getTreeViewer().addSelectionChangedListener(new ISelectionChangedListener()
      {

        @Override
        public void selectionChanged(SelectionChangedEvent event)
        {
          IStructuredSelection selection = (IStructuredSelection) prefDialog.getTreeViewer().getSelection();
          if (selection.size() == 1)
          {
            IPreferenceNode node = (IPreferenceNode) selection.getFirstElement();
            lastSelectedPageID = node.getId();
          }
        }
      });

      prefDialog.open();
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  // some code
}
```

I did try to set size for the tree:

```
TreeViewer tV = prefDialog.getTreeViewer();
Tree tree = tV.getTree();
tree.setSize(300, 800);
tree.redraw();
tree.layout();
```

but did not help. I did try to set width for the 1st child of dialog (tree), no success. Another approach was:

```
for (Control c0 : children)
{
    Point c0_cS = c0.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT);
    c0.setSize(c0_cS);
    c0.redraw();
    if (c0 instanceof Composite)
      ((Composite) c0).layout();

}
```

There is `org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog.lastTreeWidth` set to 180 by default, but I was no successful to override this value.

Comment: You are probably going to have to do some debugging since no one else will be running like this. See what `PreferencePage.computeSize` is calculating. Look at what `PreferenceDialog.showPage` is calculating for the size.

Comment: Hi @greg-449, thanks for the comment. If I understand it correctly, those methods return size of Preference page, but I need width of tree which displays contents.

Answer (score 0):

I have got ugly solution, but can not find something better. Before Preference dialog opens, I call:

```
private void resizeContentsTree(PreferenceDialog prefDialog)
{
  Tree tree = prefDialog.getTreeViewer().getTree();
  if (tree == null)
    return;

  Composite parent = tree.getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent();
  if (parent == null)
    return;

  Control contents = parent.getChildren()[0];
  Control prefPage = parent.getParent().getChildren()[0];
  if (contents instanceof Composite && prefPage instanceof Composite)
    resizeContentsTree((Composite) prefPage, (Composite) contents, 100);
}
```

and

```
private void resizeContentsTree(Composite prefPage, Composite contents, int shiftBorder)
{
    int shift = shiftBorder - prefPage.getBounds().x;
    GridData data = (GridData) contents.getLayoutData();
    int newWidthHint = data.widthHint + shift;
    if (newWidthHint < 20) {
      return;
    }
    Point computedSize = prefPage.getShell().computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT);
    Point currentSize = prefPage.getShell().getSize();
    // if the dialog wasn't of a custom size we know we can shrink
    // it if necessary based on sash movement.
    boolean customSize = !computedSize.equals(currentSize);
    data.widthHint = newWidthHint;
    //setLastTreeWidth(newWidthHint);
    prefPage.layout(true);
    // recompute based on new widget size
    computedSize = prefPage.getShell().computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT);
    // if the dialog was of a custom size then increase it only if
    // necessary.
    if (customSize) {
      computedSize.x = Math.max(computedSize.x, currentSize.x);
    }
    computedSize.y = Math.max(computedSize.y, currentSize.y);
    
    if (computedSize.equals(currentSize)) {
      return;
    }
    prefPage.getShell().setSize(computedSize.x, computedSize.y);
    //lastShellSize = getShell().getSize();
}
```